# Avoid "stack smashing detected" when recursively listing file or directories

Tags: ruby, optimization, filesystems

I've to rename around 5 000 folders located in a remote storage. Running `Dir['**/*/']` returns an error "`*** stack smashing detected ***`" and invites me to report the bug as it might occurs during the interpretation process (see [bug report](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/17162))

If it can help, here's the script I was planning to run (works fine on a test environment, though it's quite specific to my needs)

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# Fetch root directories 
dirs = Dir['**/*/'].select { |d| d =~ /\d([\.-]{1}\d{2,})?/ }

# Order subdirectories first
dirs = dirs.sort_by { |d| d.count('/') }.reverse

# Substitute "." and "-" placed after the last "/" with "_"
dirs.each do |dir|
  File.rename(dir, dir.gsub(/[\.-](?!.*\/.*)/, '_'))
end
```

Any suggestion for mitigating this issue ?

Comment: I suppose you can use `shell` to achieve your goal https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37355/recursively-rename-subdirectories-that-match-a-regex Or a similar approach.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it's on a Windows environment but it should work if I run this from WSL

Comment: I think it would be really helpful if you were to include a script in your bug report that creates all the directories and files necessary to reproduce the issue, as it's possible that reproduction is dependent upon them. It would help the developers a lot if you provided two scripts: one that recreates the issue, and another that does not, so that you can say for example "it works fine until you add the nth directory at depth x, then it crashes."

Comment: You right, I'll make tests tomorrow and upload the script if I can generate errors. I wonder if it's related to the amount of directory, the deepness of subdirectories, or the infrastructure itself (WSL + logged as network admin + local interpreter + remote storage ...). Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

It's neither a well formed question, nor a generic answer, but I managed to get around the issue by specifying the deepness to look at. Concretely, I replaced `Dir['**/*/']` by `Dir['*/*/*/*/']`.

However I'm open to other suggestions, as others may face similar issues without the possibility to hardcode the deepness to look at.

Comment: I expect you meant `Dir['*/*/*/*/']`. This would be better suited as an addumdum to you question as it's not really an answer.

Comment: You might have better luck with [`Find`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/find/rdoc/Find.html) from the standard library. More work but probably more scaleable.

Comment: Indeed Cary, I'll edit my answer ! Thanks mu, I will test it tomorrow if I've enough time and I will keep you updated